# Can I use a virtual machine from a previus subscription in azure with a new one?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I had a virtual machine in azure, after a while I stooped using it so I closed my account, everything was supposed to get deleted but now I need to work again in this machine so, I subscribed again and entered the portal.

As a nice surprise, my old virtual machine is still there but, its associated to my old account and it seems like I can't be able to activate it again.

Is there a way for me to activate my old virtual machine and associate it to my new account? or else, why is it still there?

thanks

**UPTADE:**

This is what I did to create a new virtual machine:

1. Create new storage
2. Make copy with azCopy command from old storage to the new one, it takes a while and it copies 6 files.
3. Inside the virtual machine tab in portal selected "new" to create a new virtual machine
4. Selected "from gallery option"
5. Selected Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 and then hit the arrow ->
6. Defined a name for the machine, a new username and password, selected standar layer ->
7. Selected "create a new service in cloud", gave it the same name as the machine, selected the new subscription, selected the same region I did for the storage I created, select the storage I created before and added none availability group. ->
8. In the last page I left everything as it was, so only the virtual machine agent gets installed, with no extensions and hit the finish link

Then when I open my newly created virtual machine I get a blanked machine without the programs and files I had in the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get some time between account closure and when the data gets permanently deleted. I'm guessing you're somewhere between that duration.

Since the Virtual Machines are essentially page blobs stored in blob storage, you can certainly reuse them. However for that you would need to copy the files from your old storage account (from your old subscription) to new storage account (in your new subscription). But you don't have to download them to your computer and upload them as Simon suggested. **`Azure Blob Storage supports server side async copy between storage accounts`** so you use that. It will be much faster. You can use `AzCopy` tool to copy files from one storage account to another.

However I recommend that you do the copy **now** before your previous storage account gets deleted. Because if the account gets deleted, you won't be able to copy the blobs.

**UPDATE**

Try this syntax for copying VHDs from your old storage account to new storage account:

```
AzCopy "https://<oldaccountname>.blob.core.windows.net/<oldaccountcontainername .. usually vhds>/" "https://<newaccountname>.blob.core.windows.net/<newaccountcontainername .. again vhds>/" "<filenametocopy.extension"  /SourceKey:<oldaccountkey> /DestKey:<newaccountkey> /BlobType:page /S
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a big help, although I'm still having trouble, when I try doing the copy, if I use for source: http://<<source account name>> I get a "Can't resolve remote host" exception and when I try http://<<source account name>>.blob.core.windows.net/ I get a 404 error, do you know how should the url be to access the blobs? thanks

Comment: Updated my answer with a sample command to use AzCopy for cross account copy blob. Do try it out.

Comment: Hi, I did the copy and created a virtual machine from the resulting storage but I didn't got my previous virtual machine, what am I missing?

Comment: Can you please describe what you mean by that? It will help if you posted exact steps you took. Thanks.

Comment: Actually you would have to convert the vhds you copied into disks/images (OS disk) and create the VM from those. The reason you don't see your changes is because you created a brand new VM from one the standard images available.

Answer (score 0):

If the underlying VM disk had something really valuable, try to see if the associated storage account still contains underlying vhds - if so you could try downloading it and then upload it as a OS disk using powershell to reuse

Comment: Why download to a computer and back to Azure? This could take hours or days. As @Gaurav mentioned, a blob-to-blob copy will do fine. And it's pretty easy to use an existing vhd as a data disk (or reuse original OS disk as new OS disk).

Comment: @DavidMakogon maybe I'm wrong but it seems like downloading the VHD might be the only way to get a VM that's associated w/ one tenant moved to a different tenant.  It's not as simple as just moving from one subscription to another when both subscriptions are associated with the same tenant.

Comment: @imjosh I'm not exactly sure what you're saying but... storage copy operations can go between any two storage accounts, whether in the same subscription or different subscriptions. All that's needed is an account name + key. Where you copy to (e.g. storage account/container/blob) is simply a matter of choice.

Comment: Thanks David.  Looked a little harder and maybe I can do it w/ azcopy.    I'll just try it and see.  My confusion comes from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/resource-group-move-resources/  which says "You can also move resources to a new subscription (however the subscription must exist within the same tenant). " That is for moving resources but sounds like it might not apply to storage copy operations.